# How can I just change the language of Safari in iPhone iOS 9?

Tags: ios, safari, language

I am using an iPhone with iOS 9 and the language is set to 'English'.

Also Safari's language is set to English. Is there a way to change the language *just of Safari*?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to override the language setting in Safari only.

There are multiple workarounds, though.

Google Chrome for iOS can help you translate web pages that are not in your language to something that is in your language. Google Chrome for iOS os a great browser for iOS.

To translate from any language to any language from any web browser use this(make sure to replace): https://translate.google.com/translate?&u={URL GOES HERE}. Or, just go to [this link](https://translate.google.com/).
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Safari, like other system applications in iOS, uses the system language settings to determine its display language. Unfortunately, there isn't a way to override this on a per-app setting in iOS.

What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? There may be another way.

Sorry the outcome isn't better.

Comment: When I perform a search with Google, results are shown in English, since the home page is automatically set in English. Maybe best solution can be changing the home page to another Google one, referred to another language.

Answer (score -2):

Just open a safari browser > bookmarks (the button looks like a book) > swipe left to delete Chinese sites in Favorites and Bookmarks. Then add your own bookmarks/favorites that you like when you visit a page e.g Apple.com (without the ".cn" as that's Apple China site).